# How to translate placeholder?

Tags: translation

I don't know how to translate text that I use as placeholder for my comment form. I have a  function in my function.php file where is defined how comment form should look like. Here is example of that code:

```
    $fields =  array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
                '<input id="author" name="author" placeholder="Name" type="text" required value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"> ' .
                '<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" required value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url">' .
                '<input id="url" name="url" placeholder="Website" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
     );
```

Can you help me here?

Comment: What is 'placeholder' supposed to be? What should the result look like?

Comment: Placeholder for exampe, for author is "Name". And I would like to add "Name" into .PO file so that user can change it. I tried to add placeholder="'._e( 'Name', 'tpmoments' ).'" but it doesnt work. @s_ha_dum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are concatenating a string but you are (from a comment) using a function that `echo`s information-- `_e()`. You can't do that. You are printing the content wherever that array is constructed, which is not what you want.

Use [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) instead.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, I used echo to get information from function. Works perfect!